# Is the definition of machine learning by Mitchell in his book "Machine Learning" valid?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, definitions

Mitchell's definition of machine learning is as follows:

> A computer program is said to learn from experience E with respect to some task T and performance measure P, if its performance at task T, as measured by P, improves with experience E.

Here, we talk about what it means for a **program** to learn rather than a **machine**, but a program and a machine aren't equivalent, so this is a definition about "program learning" rather than "machine learning". How is this consistent?

Answer (score 2):

Think of a computer as a [Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)--this idea is a [model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation), and all of modern computing is based on the [Turing-Church thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

Machine and program can be interchangeable—at the end of the day, it's all [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm), whether hard coded in the form of microchip, or in the form of software.  (Any microchip can be emulated as software.)

Pre-modern computers were mechanical in popular sense. Examples include Babbage's 
 [difference engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine), and [mechanical calculators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_calculator) in general.  These led to [programmable mechanical calculators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_calculator#Programmable_mechanical_calculators) and electromechanical computers such as IBM's [Harvard Mark I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Mark_I), based on Babbage's notion of an [Analytic Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine).

In this context, Machine Learning may also connote software that runs on a machine (hardware) as opposed to human/animal learning, which utilizes a biological medium.

---

The etymology of "mechanics", and by extension, "machine" is worth looking at.

- [mechanisma](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmechanisma) (in the sense of "mechanism")
- [mechanicus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmechanicus) (in the sense of "belonging to mechanics")
- [mechanema](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmechanema) (in the sense of "a trick")

*Mechanema* is instructive in that math and engineering can be understood as the "trick to doing things". ([Machination](https://www.etymonline.com/word/machination) is not pejorative in this sense, as "noun of action from past participle stem of *machinari* 'contrive skillfully, to design; to scheme, to plot,'"—one can plot the course of a celestial body.)

**Early uses of the *mech-* root**

Aristotle's [Μηχανικά](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanics_(Aristotle)) (["Mechanical Problems"](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Aristotle/Mechanica*.html)*)

Euler's [Mechanica](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/mechvol1/preface.pdf) (Euler was referring to [Classical Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics), an analytic and predictive science made possible by calculus, which is based on functions.)